# Solving the trigonometric equation $\sin^2x + \cos x = \cos^2x$ in $[0, 2\pi[$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[image: trigonometric functions]
So, as you can see in the photo above, I solved this equation and I got $2$ results as an answer. But my teacher stated that there actually are $3$ answers. The third one being $4\pi/3$. This occurs because, according to him: [image: arccos]. When I use my calculator it only gave me back the number $2\pi/3$. With all of that being stated, how can it be that there are three different solutions for this equation if the highest exponent is $2$? I mean, isn't it that the highest exponent dictates the number of solutions that an equation has?.

P.S. In case that you are wondering, Solución means solution in Spanish.

Edit: en means in.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  It would be best to type your work rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.

Comment: By using the arccosine function, you found all the solutions in the interval $[0, \pi]$.  However, you must find all solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi[$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nicholas Robino has nicely explained why there are more solutions than your calculator gave you: it's rather like how when you ask the calculator for $\sqrt{2}$, you correctly only get one of the two numbers which satisfy $x^2 = 2$. We call the positive solution to that equation "**the** square root of $2$", and your calculator will give it to you. Similarly the calculator chooses one canonical solution to $\cos x = \frac{-1}{2}$, and gives it to you under the name $\mathrm{arccos}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)$, even though there are many other solutions to that equation and it turns out that another of those solutions is also relevant to your answer.

To address the last part of your question:

> I mean, isn't it that the highest exponent dictates the number of solutions that an equation has?

Yes, *if that equation is a polynomial*. But $\sin^2(x) + \cos(x) = \cos^2(x)$ is not a polynomial in $x$, so when you solve it for $x$, there's no reason to expect it to have any particular number of solutions. Think of $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$, which has infinitely many solutions even though it's of lower degree than your original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculator only gives you $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ because they are certain domain restrictions that your calculator has to take into account when using the inverse trigonometric functions. Recall that a function can only have an inverse when it is one-to-one, so the only way to get an inverse for cosine is to restrict its domain. Since $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\cos(\pi) = -1$, if we restrict the domain of cosine to the interval $[0,\pi]$, then we have a one-to-one function, so it makes sense to talk about its inverse. Now, the domain of a function is the same as the range of its inverse, so the range of $\arccos(x)$ is $[0,\pi]$. This means that your calculator will only give you $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and not $\frac{4\pi}{3}$, because $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ is not in the range of $\arccos(x)$.

Now recall the unit circle. [image: unitcircle] From this we can certainly see that $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$, but we can also see that $\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$. In conclusion, be very familiar with the unit circle, it often comes in useful! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When $\cos(x)=-\frac12,$ there are [infinitely many solutions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kryqqb8cup) in $(-\infty,\infty),$ due to the periodic nature of the $\cos$ function.

In general, $$\cos x=k\iff \text{for some }n\in\mathbb Z,\, x=2n\pi \pm \arccos k.$$

Answer (score 0):

*Another way to look at the problem.*

Using the tangent half-angle subtitution $x=2 \tan^{-1}(t)$, the equation becomes
$$\frac{2 t^2 \left(t^2-3\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}=0$$ so the roots are $t=0$ and $t=\pm \sqrt 3$ and then the angles $x=0$, $x=\frac{2\pi}3$ and $x=\frac{4\pi}3$